# Remove Autocomplete Drop-Down Arrow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

Is there a way to remove the drop-down arrow icon from the material-ui Autocomplete react component?

This is what mine looks like now, I want to get rid of the blue arrow and instead have text drop-down automatically as I type.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Native prop [freeSolo](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#free-solo) may help you

```
<Autocomplete
  id="free-solo-demo"
  freeSolo
  options={top100Films.map((option) => option.title)}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField {...params} label="Placeholder" margin="normal" variant="outlined" />
  )}
/>
```

[image]

Comment: `freeSolo` also changes the behavior completely. See my answer below for a API provided way to hide the dropdown icon/button.

Comment: this shouldn't be accepted since we are changing other behaviours

Answer (score 13):

In MUI v5 there is a clean option to hide the Dropdown/PopUp Icon via the [`forcePopupIcon`](https://mui.com/api/autocomplete/#:%7E:text=forcePopupIcon) prop.

```js
<Autocomplete
  forcePopupIcon={false}
  // other props...
/>
```

This is much superior to the `freeSolo` option as it doesn't change the behavior of the AutoComplete. It also completely removes the InputAdornment instead of hiding it with CSS solutions.

Comment: This should be the top answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me, adding the props "popupIcon":

```
return (
    <Autocomplete
      freeSolo={false}
      popupIcon={""}
      ...
    />
```

https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/

Comment: This *looks* right but still has a blank button on the right side of the form

Answer (score 1):

Adding `freeSolo` attribute to `Autocomplete` enables us to enter the values which are not in the dropdown options.

Incase if you need the only the values in dropdown to be entered in the input, we can achieve this overriding the CSS Property of the `Autocomplete` component like this

```
const autocompleteStyles = AutocompleteStyles();
return (
    <Autocomplete
      classes={autocompleteStyles}
      freeSolo
      options={top100Films.map((option) => option.title)}
      renderInput={(params) => (
         <TextField {...params} label="Placeholder" margin="normal" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
) 
const AutocompleteStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    endAdornment: {
        display: 'none'
    }
}))
```

Refer this material ui link for more details. https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/

Answer (score 1):

[One answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63266611) specified to use: `<Select IconComponent={undefined} ... />`. However, this didn't work for me.

Instead `<Select IconComponent="none" ... />` worked, but it gives a `<none>` tag in the HTML and the browser gives a warning.

Comment: Just use `IconComponent="span"` or any other valid HTML element. No arrow, no warning.

Comment: Thanks, I have already did it and it worked!

Comment: If you use a typescript you should add `IconComponent="span"` from the comment above. If you use  `IconComponent="none"` or `IconComponent={undefined}` you would have an error `TS2322: Type '"none"' is not assignable to type 'ElementType<any>'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IconComponent` prop from the `Select` API [documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/select/#props)

Try doing something like this:

`<Select IconComponent={undefined} ... />`